# Entry Point Not Found : The procedure entry point PssQuerySnapshot could not be located in the dynamic link library ...\python312.dll

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I am trying to compile an .exe from a python script using the pyninstaller with command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile sql.py
```

When I execute the compiled .exe file on the computer on which I compile the program, the exe works. When I move it to a computer on which I do not have python installed, I get the following error:

Entry Point Not Found : The procedure entry point PssQuerySnapshot could not be located in the dynamic link library C:...\python312.dll.

Windows platform, python version 3.12.0

```
pip freeze:
altgraph==0.17.4
packaging==23.2
pefile==2023.2.7
pyinstaller==6.1.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2023.10
pymssql==2.2.10
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.2
setuptools==68.2.2
```

Can anybody help me?

I search for info over internet, but without success

Comment: That [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processsnapshot/nf-processsnapshot-pssquerysnapshot) is found in the built-in Windows kernel32.dll.

Comment: Hi @MarkTolonen,
Can you tell me what to do to make the exe to work on another computer?

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same issue as you did. I don't know much about your system, so this might not apply to you, but I'll answer anyway in case it helps out somebody else in the future.

My problem was that my Windows version (on the testing computer, i.e. Windows Server 2012) was too old, and didn't support my Python version (3.12, just like in your case).

To solve the problem:

- Install an older Python version on the computer you're compiling your code on. In my case, Python 3.7 was sufficient. You can find a full list of all available installations at https://www.python.org/downloads/windows. Of course, you'll need to check your script and might have to fix some errors due to this version change.
- Locate the new Python installation on your device. In my case, it was automatically installed at "*C:\Users\<ME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37*". You should find a "*python.exe*" file in there.
- Open a terminal, navigate to the new installation's location and install *pyinstaller* for this Python version:

```
cd "C:\Users\<ME>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37"
.\python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller
```

- Compile your python script from there:

```
.\python.exe -m PyInstaller --onefile sql.py
```

N.b.: beware the case of "*PyInstaller*".

Hope this helps!